# Long texts not sending; if I set my phone to split them up, some don't go through

Tags: sms, motorola-droid-razr, go-sms

I have a Droid RAZR and I'm on Verizon, and when I try to send a text that's over 2x160 characters to another Verizon phone, it usually doesn't send.  In the message details, my phone says "Received", but the other person doesn't get the text.  This has been happening for a while, but it's only gotten bad recently - before, I would have to reach 5x160 characters in order for it not to send.  Texts sent to non-Verizon phones seem to send fine.

To try to get around it, I set my SMS app (I use GoSMS) to always split up my messages.  What happens now is that some of the messages in the batch don't go through, regardless of the number of messages.

I would ideally like to not need to have my phone set to split my messages automatically, and be sure that long messages are going through.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Please could you try using the default SMS app - it could be an issue with GOSMS, albeit unlikely.

This also sounds like a network issue. Please contact your network (Verizon, in this case), and check with them to ensure it is nothing on their end.

Comment: I will try.  I doubt it's an issue with GoSMS - a few friends who are also on Verizon have been using it without problems, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

After the 160 char threshold messages become MMS I believe. MMS of course uses your data connection. If you have poor data connectivity in your area or have some sort of mms restriction or other account based mms alteration, this may also be the cause.

Comment: I believe the otherwise though... that for above 160 chars, they will be still split as multiple SMS messages. But I guess it may vary from telco to others.